# Spring Boot Application immediately shuts down after starting

Tags: spring, windows, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am working currently on a project which includes the Spring Framework. Everything is working as aspect but there is one problem. When I try to start my application onto my laptop it immediately shuts down after startup. **It is working on every other machine, so this problem occurs only on my laptop.**

Maybe you got an idea what could force this problem ? I am working with **IntelliJ** and I haven´t found any solutions for this problem.
**PC Specs**

- Laptop is a AsusN550JK( modified RAM and SSD)
- Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU@2.4 GHz
- 16 GB Ram
- 500 GB SSD Samsung EVO 840
- 1 TB HDD
- 64 Bit OS - Windows 10

**ConsoleOutput**

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



2017-04-22 21:24:15.756  INFO 6300 --- [           main] com.objectbay.test.me.Application        : Started Application in 8.012 seconds (JVM running for 9.251)
2017-04-22 21:24:15.758  INFO 6300 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6fb0d3ed: startup date [Sat Apr 22 21:24:08 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-22 21:24:15.763  INFO 6300 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-04-22 21:24:15.764  INFO 6300 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-22 21:24:15.765  INFO 6300 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-04-22 21:24:15.771 DEBUG 6300 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table person if exists
2017-04-22 21:24:15.782  INFO 6300 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**pom.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-accessing-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**Full example which is not working on my machine**
[Spring Guide Rest example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

**Console - LOG after Updating Dependencies**
[LOG after Updating Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2qL7.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried running the app with `debug=true` set in your properties or yml to see if there's any additional log output.

Comment: Where do I have to implement the debug=true in the pom.xml ?

Comment: you set it in the application.properties or application.yml

Comment: Looks like Tomcat dependency jar in the `.m2` cache is corrupted. Remove it and let Maven download the fresh copy.

Comment: Please provide the fresh log when starting from Maven that would be without the warning about Tomcat.

Comment: Log is atrached as pic

Comment: Can you try the same with the [most recent revision](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest/archive/master.zip) of this sample project?

Comment: This file is starts up! Amazing, but what is missing in the other project that it doesnt start ?

Comment: Do the diff between the two to see what can affect it.

Comment: `mvn clean install` fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem is solved - thanks for your help crazycoder. 
The issue was caused by an older version of tomcat. After upating the embedded tomcat of Spring to 1.5.3_RELEASE and updating  mysql-jdbc-driver as well , it finally worked for me.
I adjusted the pom.xml like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: In case it is not the above problem, It happens sometimes when the jar is corrupt. Typically I run mvn clean package and it fixes it.

Answer (score 35):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>          
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 13):

For me what caused this was that I had this property below, in the application properties (carried over by mistake from a test application.properties file). See if any of your property files that are included have this like below, and remove it:

```
# disables the servlet-container initialization (for unit testing only)
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Comment: Sweet, this is exactly what happened to me. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: For me it was this as well.

Comment: Thank you! This is my exact issue

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, I fix by these steps as below:
update file **application.yml**

1- remove:

```
main:
    web-application-type: none
```

2- if your change server port already, it's still error:

> Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or
> configure this application to listen on another port.

**solution:** move server port config on the top of yml file

Done! it's for my case.