# Stopping "Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory shutdown"

Tags: sql, azure, spring-boot

**    I'm trying to connect my Spring boot application to an Azure SQL cloud database. But my spring boot application shutdown without giving errors now. I want to stop it and listen to my Azure SQL database. Now I just want to check that spring boot is connected with the Azure database. Please tell me if there is a good way to do it.
    **

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe"
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=64378:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\Private\IIT\L5\Sem - 2\SDGP\Backend_2\Mealize with Azure\Mealize\target\classes;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter\2.2.0\azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.2.2.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.2.2.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.2.2.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\adal4j\1.6.4\adal4j-1.6.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\oauth2-oidc-sdk\6.5\oauth2-oidc-sdk-6.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.6.1\javax.mail-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\github\stephenc\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0-1\jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\lang-tag\1.4.4\lang-tag-1.4.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\nimbus-jose-jwt\8.10\nimbus-jose-jwt-8.10.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.13\commons-codec-1.13.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.9\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.2\jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.10.2\jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.2\jackson-core-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\azure-spring-boot-starter\2.2.0\azure-spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.31\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.31.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.18.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\azure-spring-boot\2.2.0\azure-spring-boot-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\7.4.1.jre8\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.8\byte-buddy-1.10.8.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.5\aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.2\HikariCP-3.4.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.1.Final\jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.4.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar" project.mealize.Mealize.MealizeApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-16 13:20:57.131  INFO 14064 --- [           main] p.mealize.Mealize.MealizeApplication     : Starting MealizeApplication on DESKTOP-6C6BSF1 with PID 14064 (started by User in D:\Private\IIT\L5\Sem - 2\SDGP\Backend_2\Mealize with Azure\Mealize)
2020-03-16 13:20:57.138  INFO 14064 --- [           main] p.mealize.Mealize.MealizeApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-16 13:20:58.543  INFO 14064 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-16 13:20:58.708  INFO 14064 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 149ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-16 13:20:59.940  INFO 14064 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-16 13:21:01.491  INFO 14064 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-16 13:21:01.565  INFO 14064 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-16 13:21:01.670  INFO 14064 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-16 13:21:01.889  INFO 14064 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-16 13:21:02.170  INFO 14064 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-03-16 13:21:03.730  INFO 14064 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-16 13:21:03.745  INFO 14064 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-16 13:21:04.626  INFO 14064 --- [           main] p.mealize.Mealize.MealizeApplication     : Started MealizeApplication in 8.354 seconds (JVM running for 10.429)
2020-03-16 13:21:04.635  INFO 14064 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-16 13:21:04.641  INFO 14064 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-16 13:21:05.041  INFO 14064 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mealizeserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=Mealize;user=dbman@mealizeserver;password=pword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
package project.mealize.Mealize.model;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="UserDetails")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String email;
    private String username;;
    private String password;
    private int age;

    public UserDetails(){}

    public UserDetails(String email,String username, String password, int age) {
        this.email=email;;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package project.mealize.Mealize.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import project.mealize.Mealize.model.UserDetails;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDetails, String> {
}
```

Comment: There's a few old questions [e.g. this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562170/spring-boot-application-immediately-shuts-down-after-starting) that say this can be a problem with spring-boot-starter, or a mismatched version of Tomcat, or a corrupted copy of Tomcat, in case any of those are your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I removed this line

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

from `application.properties` file

Comment: This works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue in openshift deployment, there was no error/exception but the pod was showing auto shutdown. This was resolved by increasing the liveness and readiness probe timeout.

[ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence ..

The error message could be seen while trying to manually shutdown application from terminal.