# Spring Application shutdown after Tomcat started - HikariPool - Shutdown initiated

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to publish a Spring Rest App using Render but I am going through this issue for a long time. Using my local environment everything works like a charm, I have a Dockerfile which copies the .jar package and then uses the entrypoint to start the app.

Dockerfile, POM & logs as follows. Honestly I don't have any clue, I tried almost everything but still keep having the same issue in Render (hosting service). Second option is to use another hosting, so far I don't recall any other free one.

```
FROM amazoncorretto:19-alpine-jdk
COPY package/PortfolioAPI.jar /PortfolioAPI.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/PortfolioAPI.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portfolio.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest</name>
    <description>Portfolio API Rest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                        <version>0.11.5</version>
                </dependency>
                                <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>0.11.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                        <version>0.11.5</version>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
                <finalName>PortfolioAPI</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
May 2 10:04:03 PM  
May 2 10:04:39 PM  
May 2 10:04:39 PM    .   ____          _            __ _ _
May 2 10:04:39 PM   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
May 2 10:04:39 PM  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
May 2 10:04:39 PM   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
May 2 10:04:39 PM    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
May 2 10:04:39 PM   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
May 2 10:04:39 PM   :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.4)
May 2 10:04:39 PM  
May 2 10:04:41 PM  2023-05-03T01:04:41.731Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.portfolio.api.rest.RestApplication   : Starting RestApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 19.0.2 with PID 1 (/PortfolioAPI.jar started by root in /)
May 2 10:04:41 PM  2023-05-03T01:04:41.885Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.portfolio.api.rest.RestApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
May 2 10:05:08 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:08.947Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
May 2 10:05:11 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:11.047Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1890 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
May 2 10:05:35 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:35.950Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
May 2 10:05:36 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:36.267Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
May 2 10:05:36 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:36.345Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
May 2 10:05:40 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:40.748Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
May 2 10:05:40 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:40.847Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 57085 ms
May 2 10:05:46 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:46.546Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
May 2 10:05:48 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:48.149Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
May 2 10:05:57 PM  2023-05-03T01:05:57.954Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
May 2 10:06:10 PM  2023-05-03T01:06:10.742Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1d4664d7
May 2 10:06:10 PM  2023-05-03T01:06:10.753Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
May 2 10:06:11 PM  2023-05-03T01:06:11.067Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
May 2 10:06:11 PM  2023-05-03T01:06:11.165Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
May 2 10:06:45 PM  2023-05-03T01:06:45.714Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
May 2 10:06:45 PM  2023-05-03T01:06:45.854Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
May 2 10:07:08 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:08.853Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
May 2 10:07:18 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:18.847Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@54e12f4c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@60990e5c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2954f6ab, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@58af5076, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4d84049a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6fff46bf, com.portfolio.api.rest.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter@3f183caa, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@163042ea, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1fbf088b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@39ee94de, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@52b46d52, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@73aeef7d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2db33feb]
May 2 10:07:25 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:25.755Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
May 2 10:07:26 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:26.752Z  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
May 2 10:07:26 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:26.855Z  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
May 2 10:07:26 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:26.860Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.portfolio.api.rest.RestApplication   : Started RestApplication in 184.698 seconds (process running for 202.199)
May 2 10:07:28 PM  2023-05-03T01:07:28.145Z  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I tried removing unnecessary dependencies, using different docker images and POM configurations....no luck at all. Since it works perfect using my local docker image I am completely lost.

Comment: How are you consuming the database credentials? If you're using an external secrets manager, make sure your container can successfully connect to it. Also, what are the firewall rules on your database instance?

Comment: Check this out, try to update the Mysql pom version and the embeded tomcat version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562170/spring-boot-application-immediately-shuts-down-after-starting

Comment: Yes, I have already updated mysql dialect and also tried embedding the tomcat....no luck. Still fails in Render...but since I am using the docker file it should be an identical image :'(.